# How integrate Selenium Grid 2 With Hudson/Jenkins?

Tags: git, testng, selenium-grid2

I would like to know how to integrate selenium Grid 2 and Jenkins on Windows or Linux both are fine with me. (I am able to run Selenium Grid 2 alone successfully on the same machine and on different machines using TestNG and Java)

Should we use Ant to build (currently using GIT as version control sys)? Does Jenkins/Hudson's Selenium Grid plugin support Grid 2? If so how can we achieve this integration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE: On 26/12/2011 the Jenkins grid plugin was upgraded to use Selenium2 
   https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin

---

There is a Selenium Grid Plugin for Jenkins https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin .

However, the jenkins plugin is based on the old Selenium Grid (v1) ( but should work with some quirks with webdriver/selenium2 ).

There is a ticket open on the Jenkins bug tracker [Upgrade Selenium Grid Plugin to Selenium Grid 2.0](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-8580). Maybe voting for this ticket on the Jenkins Jira would speed up the things...